# djongo RunPython in database migration

Tags: django, django-migrations, djongo

There's a django app with djongo as database driver. I want to add custom migration using `RunPython`. But I can't understand how to reach pymongo client. Here's the code:

```
from django.db import migrations


def _custom_migration(apps, schema_editor):
    db = ... # what to put here?
    db.collection1.update_many({}, [{'$set': {"field2": "$field1.id"}}])


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(_custom_migration),
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reach PyMongo:

- [client](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#making-a-connection-with-mongoclient) (`MongoClient` instance) from `schema_editor.connection.client_connection`.
- [db](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#getting-a-database) (`Database` instance) from `schema_editor.connection.connection`.

```py
def _custom_migration(apps, schema_editor):
    db = schema_editor.connection.connection
    db.collection1.update_many({}, [{'$set': {"field2": "$field1.id"}}])
```

Source references:

- [`schema_editor.connection`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3bbe22d/django/db/backends/base/schema.py#L147-L148) [holds](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3bbe22d/django/db/backends/base/base.py#L721) the `DatabaseWrapper` instance.
- [`DatabaseWrapper.client_connection`](https://github.com/doableware/djongo/blob/0211e8f/djongo/base.py#L176) [holds](https://github.com/doableware/djongo/blob/0211e8f/djongo/database.py#L8-L14) the `MongoClient` instance.
- [`(Base)DatabaseWrapper.connection`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3bbe22d/django/db/backends/base/base.py#L256) [holds](https://github.com/doableware/djongo/blob/0211e8f/djongo/base.py#L179-L181) the `Database` instance.

Answer (score 0):

from documentation https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html try this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

def _custom_migration(apps, schema_editor):
    client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    db = client.test_database
    db.collection1.update_many({}, [{'$set': {"field2": "$field1.id"}}])
```

Comment: Does not it look like a little hack? I mean there's a `schema_editor` object, is it ok not to use it, but create a new client instead?